# Prove that if $f(\lambda x) = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^N f(x)$ than $|f(x)| \leq c \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|^N$

Tags: inequality

The task is:

Knowing that $\forall \lambda >0, x \neq 0$

$f(\lambda x) = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^N f(x)$

prove that:

$|f(x)| \leq c \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|^N$

I would really appreciate any ideas as I can't come up with anything productive!

Comment: Hint: If $x>0$ then $f(x\cdot1)=\ldots f(1)$ hence... If $x<0$, ...

Comment: @Did, thanks, but do i need to separetely notice that $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ are finite?

Comment: Yes you need to use that ("separately" rather escapes me, sorry to say).

Comment: @Did Exactly, thank you very much. I was just  working on this and I wrote $\;1=\frac\lambda\lambda\;$  and then stood up and when I came I completely forgot. Deleting comments that just can bother.

Comment: @AlexM. What for?